# why cant i run WpfBrowserApplication?

Tags: c#

I did a small program which supposed to show small MessageBox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Windows;    
using System.Windows.Controls;    
using System.Windows.Data;    
using System.Windows.Documents;    
using System.Windows.Input;    
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;   
using System.Windows.Shapes; 

namespace WpfBrowserApplication1   
{  
    /// <summary>    
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml   
    /// </summary>    
    public partial class Page1 : Page    
    {   
        public Page1()    
        {    
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
        {

            MessageBox.Show("gs");    
        }   
    }    
}
```

Result:

[image]

Why? how can i get a small web page with a simple button that when you click on him show messgebox?

Comment: Post relevant code here and relevant messages.  Don't just link to it.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're using Opera.

WPF Browser Applications are only supported in IE.

There is a WPF plugin for other browsers, but I understand it's undermaintained.

Why are you developing a WPFBA anyway? It's dead-end.

Comment: what do you mean by "dead-end" ?

Comment: The WPF BA platform is not being actively maintained by Microsoft (spare security fixes), and Microsoft has embraced the notion of a more open web: proprietary web plug-ins are unfashionable.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Browser Applications are only supported in IE sorry